# Customer Order Email - How to display thumbnail of image upload by customer on email?

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

Basically in their shopping cart I would like to display the image they upload to print but i can't seem to figure it out..... I know i need to add in something along the lines of `<img src="http://path/to/thumbnails/myimage.jpg">` but i don't know what to add in place of  "http://path/to/thumbnails/myimage.jpg" within this code to display the image they upload if there even is anything? All help appreciated! Thanks (sorry if this is a silly question and plain obvious)

```
 {% comment %}

      This is your /cart template. If you are using the Ajaxify Cart plugin,
      your form (with action="/cart") layout will be used in the drawer/modal.

      For info on test orders:
        - General http://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-store/orders/test-orders
        - Shopify Payments - http://docs.shopify.com/manual/more/shopify-payments/testing-shopify-payments

    <!-- Bold: Options 4-1 --> 
    <script>function update_qty_builder(builder_id, qty){ jQuery('.'+builder_id+"_qty").val(qty.value); } function remove_product_builder(builder_id){ jQuery('.'+builder_id+"_qty").val(0); jQuery('.'+builder_id+"_qty").parents("form").submit(); }</script>
    {% include 'bold-cart-handler' %}
    <!-- // end Options 4-1 -->

    {% endcomment %}
    {% if cart.item_count > 0 %}

      <form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="cart">

        <div class="section-header">
          <h1 class="section-header__title">{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="cart__row medium-down--hide cart__header-labels">
          <div class="grid--full">
            <div class="grid__item large--one-half push--large--one-half">
              <div class="grid--full">
                <div class="grid__item one-third medium-down--one-third">
                  <span class="h4">{{ 'cart.label.price' | t }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid__item one-third medium-down--one-third text-center">
                  <span class="h4">{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid__item one-third medium-down--one-third text-right">
                  <span class="h4">{{ 'cart.label.total' | t }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {% comment %}
          Loop through products in the cart
        {% endcomment %}
        {% for item in cart.items %}
    <!-- Bold: Options 4-2 -->
    {% include 'boldoptions' with 'step2' %}
    <!-- // end Options 4-2 -->

        <tr style="{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step4' %}" class="{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step3' %}">
          <div class="cart__row" data-id="{{ item.id }}">
            <div class="grid--full cart__row--table-large">

              <div class="grid__item large--one-half">
                <div class="grid">

                  <div class="grid__item one-third">
                    <a href="{{ item.url | within: collections.all }}" class="cart__image">

                      {% comment %}
                        More image size options at:
                          - http://docs.shopify.com/themes/filters/product-img-url
                      {% endcomment %}

    <!-- Bold: Options 4-5 -->
    {% if builder[0] %}
    <img src="{{ builder[1] }}" alt="{{ builder[0] }}" /> 
    {% else %}

                      <img src="{{ item | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ item.title | escape }}">
                    </a>


    <!-- Bold: Options 4-6 -->
    {% include 'boldoptions' with 'step6' %}
    <!-- // end Options 4-6 -->

    {% endif %}
     <!-- // end Options 4-5 -->


                  </div>

                  <div class="grid__item two-thirds">
                    <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="h4">
                      {{ item.product.title }}
                    </a>
                    {% unless item.variant.title contains 'Default' %}
                      <br>
                      <small>{{ item.variant.title }}</small>
                    {% endunless %}

                    {% if settings.cart_vendor_enable %}
                      <p>{{ item.vendor }}</p>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% comment %}
                      Optional, loop through custom product line items if available

                      For more info on line item properties, visit:
                        - http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization
                    {% endcomment %}

                    {% include 'product_customizer_cart' %} 

                    {% if item.properties.size > 0 %}
                      {% for p in item.properties %}
                        {% unless p.last == blank %}
                          {{ p.first }}:

                          {% comment %}
                            Check if there was an uploaded file associated
                          {% endcomment %}
                          {% if p.last contains '/uploads/' %}
                            <a href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
                          {% else %}
                            {{ p.last }}
                          {% endif %}

                          <br>
                        {% endunless %}
                      {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    <a href="{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step9' %}" data-id="{{ item.id }}" class="{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step10' %} cart__remove" {% include 'boldoptions' with 'step11' %}>
                      <small>{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</small>
                    </a>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="grid__item large--one-half">
                <div class="grid--full cart__row--table-large">

                  <div class="grid__item one-third">
                    <span class="cart__mini-labels">{{ 'cart.label.price' | t }}</span>
                    <span class="h5">{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step12' %}</span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="grid__item one-third text-center">
                    <span class="cart__mini-labels">{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</span>
                    {% comment %}
                      Added data-id for the ajax cart implementation only.
                    {% endcomment %}
                    <input type="number" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.id }}" class="{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step7' %}" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" data-id="{{ item.id }}" {% include 'boldoptions' with 'step8' %}>
                  </div>

                  <div class="grid__item one-third text-right">
                    <span class="cart__mini-labels">{{ 'cart.label.total' | t }}</span>
                    <span class="h5">{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step13' %}</span>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="cart__row">
          <div class="grid">
            {% comment %}
              Optional, add a textarea for special notes
                - Your theme settings can turn this on or off. Default is on.
                - Make sure you have name="note" for the message to be submitted properly
            {% endcomment %}
            {% if settings.cart_notes_enable %}
              {% assign noteSize = cart.note | size %}
              <div class="grid__item large--five-twelfths">
                <button type="button" class="text-link cart__note-add{% if noteSize > 0 %} is-hidden{% endif %}">
                  {{ 'cart.label.add_note' | t }}
                </button>
                <div class="cart__note{% if noteSize > 0 %} is-active{% endif %}">
                  <label for="CartSpecialInstructions">{{ 'cart.general.note' | t }}</label>
                  <textarea name="note" class="input-full" id="CartSpecialInstructions">{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="grid__item text-right{% if settings.cart_notes_enable %} large--seven-twelfths{% endif %}">
              <p>
                <span class="cart__subtotal-title">{{ 'cart.general.subtotal' | t }}</span>
                <span class="h5 cart__subtotal">{{ cart.total_price | money }}</span>
              </p>
              <p><em>{{ 'cart.general.shipping_at_checkout' | t }}</em></p>
              <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn--secondary update-cart" value="{{ 'cart.general.update' | t }}">
              <input type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn" value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}">

              {% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
                <div class="cart__additional_checkout">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </form>

    {% else %}
      {% comment %}
        The cart is empty
      {% endcomment %}
      <h2>{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h2>
      <p>{{ 'cart.general.empty' | t }}</p>
      <p>{{ 'cart.general.continue_browsing_html' | t }}</p>
    {% endif %}


    <!-- Bold: Options 4-14 -->
    {% include 'bold-cart-modal' %}
    <!-- // end Options 4-14 -->
```

Comment: a lot of basic information missing here, clearly, your using some template engine, also need to see the mail code and the form code.

Comment: Please don't post all of your ultra long lines but rather provide more surrounding info

Comment: okay I've posted an alternative that may work even better..... any chance of this being easier to figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the full publicly reachable image path in the src attribute of the image tag

```
<img src="http://path/to/thumbnails/myimage.jpg">
```